# Return nodes if attached to set of nodes with each a specific value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have users that can put their availabilities to be booked by other users, getting the following:

```
(u:User {Id = "1"})-[:USER_AVAILABILITY]->(a:Availability {Date = "2018-07-18", Booked = false})
```

The user can have one node availability for each day he said he was available. I want to check if a user is available for example on: "2018-07-18", "2018-07-19", "2018-07-20". So I need to check that the user has all nodes related to a list of node's date values. Is it possible to do that?

I'm using the version 3.2.5 of neo4j.

I tried the following query:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.Id = '1'
MATCH (u)-[:USER_AVAILABILITY]-(a:Availability)
WHERE a.Date = '2018-07-18'
MATCH (u)-[:USER_AVAILABILITY]-(a2:Availability)
WHERE a2.Date = '2018-07-19'
MATCH (u)-[:USER_AVAILABILITY]-(a3:Availability)
WHERE a3.Date = '2018-07-20'
RETURN u
```

But obviously, it's not working because I can go through a path only one time. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with a list of values, you can use all() to ensure a predicate holds true for all values in the list. Assuming you are passing the list of dates as a parameter (let's say `$requiredDates`):

```
MATCH (u:User {id:$userId})
WHERE all(date in $requiredDates WHERE (u)-[:USER_AVAILABILITY]-(:Availability {Date:date}))
RETURN u
```

Comment: In this example, id should also be a parameter

Comment: Thanks man, works perfectly. Why should i have the id as a parameter ? Do you mean for query reuse purposes or is there something i don't know ? When i'm building my query in the driver it does it for me so i'm not confronted to the use-case, but it's for personal knowledge.

Comment: Yes, for reusing the query with different ids for the starting node.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do that :

```
MATCH (u:User {id:'1'}),
      (u)-[:USER_AVAILABILITY]-(a:Availability),
      (u)-[:USER_AVAILABILITY]-(a2:Availability),
      (u)-[:USER_AVAILABILITY]-(a3:Availability)
WHERE a.Date = '2018-07-18' AND 
      a2.Date = '2018-07-19' AND 
      a3.Date = '2018-07-20'
RETURN u
```